# Least value for addition

Tags: arithmetic

We know that $$0\leq a \leq b \leq c\leq d\leq e\,\,\text{ and}\,\, a + b + c + d + e = 100$$. What would be the least
possible value of $\,\,a + c + e\,\,$ ?

I apologize for poor syntax.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

$$2(a+c+e) =a+a+c+c+e+e \geq a+b+c+d+e =100$$

With equality if and only if $a=0$, $b=c$ and $d=e$.

Comment: Just bound the first $a$ by 0 (from below).

Comment: would this be the least value possible?

Comment: i apologise for the duplicates!

Comment: Equivalently, $a+c+e \ge 0 + b + d$ so $a+c+e \ge \frac{100}{2} = 50$ with equality iff...